# provisioner could not be found

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am new to vagrant and i am trying to launch a vagrant box with the name 'haproxy' and using ansible to deploy stuff. my vagrant file is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.define "haproxy" do |haproxy|
    config.vm.provision "haproxy" do |haproxy|
      ansible.verbose = "v"
      ansible.playbook = "Ansible_BASES/haproxy.yml"
  end
  end
end
```

But this says :

```
viper@nishstorm:~/Vagrant_TEST$ vagrant up 
Bringing machine 'haproxy' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The 'haproxy' provisioner could not be found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First You can't call a provisioner `|haproxy|`, provisioner are [strictly defined](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html), you have to declare a provisioner from the known ones. Here your provisioner is ansible has implied by the then variable `ansible.verbose`.

If the intent was to make the provisioner work with your a vm with the name 'haproxy' you can define your Vagrantfile as following:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.name = "haproxy"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.playbook = "Ansible_BASES/haproxy.yml"
  end
end
```

But you can also do it like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define 'haproxy' do |haproxy|
    haproxy.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    haproxy.ssh.insert_key = false
    haproxy.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.verbose = "v"
      ansible.playbook = "Ansible_BASES/haproxy.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: oh okay.. yes.. just one more help.. if i wanna give a hostname to the instance and also forward a port , what should be the syntex

Comment: You should check both the [machine settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) and the [forwarded port](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the provisioning plugin could help

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant provision
```